# Progress bar while running a bat file through shiny app

Tags: r, batch-file, shiny

I am running a lengthy .bat file with an action button in a shiny app. I am able to show the progress bar, however, the progress bar(blue) prints about 10% and sits there for a long time. After the .bat file is finished, then the progress bar quickly moves to 100%. My question is: How can I show the progress bar moving at all times while the .bat file is executing. The code I am using is below but I am not able to provide the .bat file that I am running because it depends on other large files.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinycssloaders)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel(h1("Progress Bar Test",align="center")),
                mainPanel(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    actionButton("buttonId", "Create exe file"))))
                   

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$buttonId, {
    withProgress(message = 'Creating executable',
                 detail = 'It takes about 30 seconds per year...',{
                   bat <- shell("mybatchfile.bat,wait=TRUE")
                   for (i in 1:length(bat)){
                     incProgress(setProgress(i/length(bat)))             
                     Sys.sleep(2)
                     
                   }
                 }    )}
           )}
  
         # Run the application 
         shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What is the length of a bat file and how is it related to the progress? How do you get the total execution time of the bat file before you start it?

Comment: The bat file takes about 30 minutes to execute multiple years of data. I execute the file manually by opening the file. Not sure if I understand your question..

Comment: The problem is, there is no way for `R` to know the progress of your code unless there are some variables created in the middle of the execution and then we can update the progress bar to a predefined progress number once the variable is created. So in your use case if a single code runs for 30 min there is no way according to my knowledge to update the progress bar.

Comment: Like @MohanGovindasamy says, you need to either pass R some values to indicate progress, or an estimated (fixed) time that you want R to use to update the progressbar.

Comment: @mhovd   I see. It makes sense. How can I go about estimated (fixed) time to update the progress bar? I would like to see some updating instead of just sitting in the same spot and quickly update to a 100% upon completion.

Comment: an YouTube [video](https://youtu.be/iZnLZFRylbs) explaining this